# Configuring SMS API

Tags: c#, winforms, api, sms

Please all I've got this API from an SMS reseller here in Nigeria. I want to know how to insert my textbox values corectly
API: `http://smsmobile24.com/components/com_spc/smsapi.php?username=xxx&password=yyy&sender=@@sender@@&recipient=@@recipient@@&message=@@message@@`

I need to insert password, username and of course sender and recipients.

I have tried doing this:

```
string to, msg;
to = smsRecipientBox.Text;
msg = smsMsgBox.Text;
```

`http://smsmobile24.com/components/com_spc/smsapi.php?username=C***er&password=fath****am&sender=Cmanager&recipient = '"+to+"'&message='"+msg+"';`

But I get that red line telling me there is an error.

Comment: And what does the red line say?

Comment: Newline in Constant and its at the end

Comment: Hi it would be easy to answer if you could provide a useful code snippet and the output. By looking at the code snippet you have provide we can't identify what has gone wrong as you have only provide the snippet of setting values for two variables. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify a constant value (variable that is marked with `const` modifier).

You have two options here:

1) you remove the `const` from the field

2) use formatting to insert values in placeholders in the constant string:

```
const string url = "http://smsmobile24.com/components/com_spc/smsapi.php?username=C***er&password=fath****am&sender=Cmanager&recipient={0}&message={1}";

var to = smsRecipientBox.Text;
var msg = smsMsgBox.Text;

string result = string.Format(url, to, msg);
```